# Permissions - Groups

Tags: google-drive-api

I'm having a look at Google Drive and we have instances where we will need item level [permissions](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/permissions#resource) on files. We have groups of people would would have write access to the file. I notice that the API allows you to set permissions on a file with a group id but am unsure how to setup the group in the first place?

Could someone please advise on how to do this?

The other alternative would be to send a permission for each user but this seems like a less ideal workaround.

Comment: it might sound less ideal, but might also be the way to go. I seem to recall some bugs/odd behaviour when the group membership changes. Whichever approach you take, use the Drive documentation's "try it now" feature to test that the behaviour is as you expect it, *before* writing any code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just share with a google group which has an email.

Comment: Thanks Zig, I understand that you can use an existing group for the security, my question is how can I manage the groups? Can you create Groups with the Drive API? Or is there a different API to use?

Comment: Thanks Zig for the link.